# unityWebRequest form post to node.js

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine

I am trying to send login data to server from unity through node.js and node.js will return id of login user. but post does not work. **C# Code**

```
form.AddField("usernamePost" , username);
            form.AddField("passwordPost" , password);
            print(username + "    " + inputPassword);

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(LoginURL,form);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        //spinner.Dismiss();
        string value= www.downloadHandler.text;
```

And this is **nodejs** code

```
app.use('/ownerLogin', (req,res) =>{
    let username=req.query.ownerIdPost;
    let userPassword=req.query.passwordPost;
    console.log(username);
    console.log(userPassword);
```

I have tried

```
req.param
req.params
req.body
```

It gives empty and **undefined** I also change request method to

```
app.get('/ownerLogin', (req,res) =>{.....
and
app.post('/ownerLogin', (req,res) =>{....
```

But nothing worked for me . Kindly help me

Comment: You are calling a `POST` method from your C# code, so indoor node part should be a post request as `app.post('/ownerLogin', (req,res) =>{....` what you did is correct. But I think you are missing `bodyparser` in your server.js. Can you post your `server.js` or `index.js`

Comment: i didnot do anything in server.js

Answer (score 0):

It worked on me using

NodeJS:

```
app.post(`/letlogin`, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username);
});
```

Unity:

```
WWWForm formData = new WWWForm () ;
formData.AddField("username", "Barodar");

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost:3001/letlogin/", formData);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```